# C: Overwrite another function byte by byte

Tags: c, function, byte

Let's suppose I have a function:

```
int f1(int x){
 // some more or less complicated operations on x
 return x;
}
```

And that I have another function

```
int f2(int x){
 // we simply return x
 return x;
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
char* _f1 = (char*)f1;
char* _f2 = (char*)f2;
int i;
for (i=0; i<FUN_LENGTH; ++i){
 f1[i] = f2[i];
}
```

I.e. I would like to interpret `f1` and `f2` as raw byte arrays and "overwrite `f1` byte by byte" and thus, replace it by `f2`.

I know that usually callable code is write-protected, however, in my particular situation, you can simply overwrite the memory location where `f1` is located. That is, I can copy the bytes over onto `f1`, but afterwards, if I call `f1`, the whole thing crashes.

So, is my approach possible in principle? Or are there some machine/implementation/whatsoever-dependent issues I have to take into consideration?

Comment: I believe "callable code is write-protected" is the answer to why it is failing.  I doubt I'm the first to say this, but self modifying code is usually either a terrible idea or a symptom of a bug.

Comment: @DwB As I mentioned in my question, I found out that I *can* write into the section where the functions are stored. Just *calling* the overwritten variant results in a crash.

Comment: also, take into consideration that f1 is probably longer than f2... i.e. is made up of more bytes

Comment: There is almost certainly a better solution to whatever the top-level problem is...

Comment: @SoboLAN Good point, but it shouldn't be a problem if `f1` is longer than `f2`, should it?

Comment: @Oli Unless the top-level problem is hacking into someone's system or beating DRM in some game.

Comment: @phimuemue I have no idea how these functions are internally represented (it's probably compiler specific) but there is probably a chunk of bytes that represent "here is where I (the function) end". If those bytes get copied also, then no, it shouldn't be a problem. If this happens or not, I do not know. What you are trying to do is very strange and I just can't think of any practical/concrete use for something like this... except cracking of course :)

Comment: @SoboLAN: Unless, of course the replacement function is longer than the original function, in which case you'll overwrite whatever code comes next as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be easier to replace the first few bytes of `f1` with a machine `jump` instruction to the beginning of `f2`. That way, you won't have to deal with any possible code relocation issues.

Also, the information about how many bytes a function occupies (`FUN_LENGTH` in your question) is normally not available at runtime. Using a `jump` would avoid that problem too.

For x86, the relative jump instruction opcode you need is `E9` (according to [here](http://siyobik.info/main/reference/instruction/JMP)). This is a 32-bit relative jump, which means you need to calculate the relative offset between `f2` and `f1`. This code might do it:

```
int offset = (int)f2 - ((int)f1 + 5); // 5 bytes for size of instruction
char *pf1 = (char *)f1;
pf1[0] = 0xe9;
pf1[1] = offset & 0xff;
pf1[2] = (offset >> 8) & 0xff;
pf1[3] = (offset >> 16) & 0xff;
pf1[4] = (offset >> 24) & 0xff;
```

The offset is taken from the *end* of the JMP instruction, so that's why there is 5 added to the address of `f1` in the offset calculation.

It's a good idea to step through the result with an assembly level debugger to make sure you're poking the correct bytes. Of course, this is all not standards compliant so if it breaks you get to keep both pieces.

Comment: That would certainly be an option. Do you know how to do this within a C program?

Comment: Sure, take the address of `f1` and cast it to a `char *`. Then, overwrite the first few bytes with an appropriate machine instruction for your architecture that causes a jump to `f2`. You may be able to use an absolute address or you may need to calculate a relative jump offset and use that. Can't say with more detail without knowing which architecture you're using.

Comment: What kind of CPU are we talking about?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Just a normal x86 proceessor.

Comment: @phimuemue: You may find the article here interesting: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27339/API-hooking-for-hotpatchable-operating-systems  It describes Microsoft's mechanism for patching that's baked right into the compiler toolchain. Probably no direct help unless you're targeting Windows, but worth a read nonetheless I think.

Comment: You should also read the paper on "Detours" written by MS Research a while back.  It's a nice explanation of the standard technique (before support by the compiler for 'hotpatching') and explains how to reasonably reliably chain back to the original function if that's what you want.  http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/68568/huntusenixnt99.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is undefined behavior for the C standard.

And on many operating systems (e.g. Linux), your example will crash: the function code is inside the read only `.text` segment (and section) of the ELF executable, and that segment is (sort-of) [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)-ed read-only by [execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) (or by `dlopen` or by the dynamic linker), so you cannot write inside it.

Comment: Yes, and not just because it tries to modify the code. Converting a function pointer to `char*` has undefined behavior.

Comment: However, casting function pointer to `void*` is permitted in the latest Posix standard (but not in the C standard, and some weird architectures have different sizes for pointer to function and pointer to data).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to overwrite the function (which you've already found is fragile at best), I'd consider using a pointer to a function:

```
int complex_implementation(int x) { 
    // do complex stuff with x
    return x;
}

int simple_implementation(int x) { 
   return x;
}

int (*f1)(int) = complex_implementation;
```

You'd use this something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) {
    a = f1(a);
    if (whatever_condition)
        f1 = simple_implementation;
}
```

...and after the assignment, calling `f1` would just return the input value.

Calling a function via a pointer does impose some overhead, but (thanks to that being common in OO languages) most compilers and CPUs do a pretty good job of minimizing that overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Most memory architectures will stop you writing over the function code.    It will crash....   But some embedded devices, you can do this kind of thing, but it is dangerous unless you know there's enough space, the calling is going to be ok, the stack is going to be ok, etc etc...

Most likely there is a WAY better way to solve the problem.